# Symfony2 Property Path Parse Error on "collection" Form

Tags: symfony

I have been trying to figure this out for over an hour and I have made no progress...

I have the following form and its the only field:

```
<?php
$builder
        ->add('cars', 'collection', array(
            'type' => new CarType(),
            //'property_path' => '[cars]',
            'required' => false,
        ))
    ;
```

This form receives an array, with one key "cars" pointing to an array of Car objects (which are handled fine by the CarType().

When I set data to this form, it gives me a Property Path parse error, stating that the property path "[]" is invalid and cant be parsed. Note that if I uncomment the property_path option above it is the same error (I just put that there to show its the default).

1. Why is it using a property path of []?
2. How can I fix this?

**NOTE: This works fine in one enviornment with PHP 5.4 and fails on all my PHP 5.3 environments.**

Thanks for any help.

**More information:**

Exception: "Could not parse property path "[]". Unexpected token "[" at position 0"

in /vagrant/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/PropertyAccess/PropertyPath.php at line 125

Comment: please add the entity holding the cars , property, getter/setter to the question. aswell as your CarType form

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem, and found this workaround, which I'll adapt to your example:

I was using the form to create some new `Car` objects, so my cars didn't have IDs. My `Car->getId()` method returned `null`.  When I changed the `getId()` method to this:

```
public function getId() {
    return (int) $this->id;
}
```

the problem went away, because now `getId()` is returning 0. Presumably the property path `[0]` is valid, but `[]` is not.

Answer (score 1):

Your return value of the `getCars()` should normally not be of type `array` but of type `Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection`.

[property_path](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#property-path) specifies the property which shall be used by the form to get/set the values back to the underlying object.

if your field-name is 'cars' it will already default to 'cars'.

Please note that you don't have to wrap the property_path's value in `[]` ...

---

PHP 5.3 does not support the short array syntax `[]` which has been added in PHP 5.4.

For backward compatibility you have to use `array()` syntax.

Comment: I don't believe anywhere in my code I am using the [] array syntax.  This seems to be an error thrown by an invalid "[]" property_path in the form component.

Comment: you don't have to wrap the property_path in [] ... and it defaults to the field-name ... you don't need it in your case

Comment: I have commented it out just to show that it will default to what is in the comment.  I still get the same error with that commented out.

Comment: jeah i got that - but the commented out value includes [] aswell, which is wrong.